# My Event-handling system

Tags: java, event-handling

I have written about 180 lines of code that implements an Event system.

I would like a general review about the code and I'd love comments about the usability of it. (Is the code useful? Would you like to use it or a similar system like it?)

#### Summary of the parts involved

- `IEvent` is a marker interface for event classes
- `Event` is an annotation that must be added for all methods that are listening to events
- `EventListener` is a marker interface for classes that wants to listen to events
- `EventHandler` is a class that is responsible for executing an event on a single `EventListener`
- `EventExecutor` is the main class that binds everything together. It is where listeners must go to get registered and it is where IEvents must go to get executed.

#### Reason for implementing

I don't want to use a whole bunch of different interfaces (one for each type of `IEvent`), along with `addThisEventHandler`, `addThatEventHandler`, `dispatchThisEvent`, `dispatchThatEvent` and a [whole bunch of other repeatedly added stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247926/java-event-listener-to-detect-a-variable-change).

I want the system to be flexible and useful mainly. Speed is not a *primary* concern, but if you see something that is having in your opinion a too heavy performance cost then I'd love to hear about it.

#### The Code (Approximately 180 code lines, not including whitespace and comments)

`CustomFacade.getLog...` is my own logging system which I don't think is relevant to the review, therefore the source is not included for this part. Besides this, the code is stand-alone (only depending on the regular Java classes, of course).

Event.java

```
/**
 * Indication that a method should handle an {@link IEvent}<br>
 * The method needs to return {@link Void} and expect exactly one parameter of a type that implements {@link IEvent}.<br>
 * Only methods in classes that implements {@link EventListener} should use this annotation.
 */
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Event {
    int priority() default 50;
}
```

EventExecutor.java

```
public class EventExecutor {
    public static final int PRE = -1;
    public static final int ALL = 0;
    public static final int POST = 1;

    private final Map<Class<? extends IEvent>, Collection<EventHandler>> bindings;
    private final Set<EventListener> registeredListeners;

    private boolean debug = false;
    public void setDebug(boolean debug) {
        this.debug = debug;
    }

    public EventExecutor() {
        this.bindings = new HashMap<Class<? extends IEvent>, Collection<EventHandler>>();
        this.registeredListeners = new HashSet<EventListener>();
    }

    public List<EventHandler> getListenersFor(Class<? extends IEvent> clazz) {
        if (!this.bindings.containsKey(clazz)) 
            return new ArrayList<EventHandler>(); // No handlers so we return an empty list
        return new ArrayList<EventHandler>(this.bindings.get(clazz));
    }

    public <T extends IEvent> T executeEvent(T event, int i) {
        Collection<EventHandler> handlers = this.bindings.get(event.getClass());
        if (handlers == null) {
            if (this.debug)
                CustomFacade.getLog().d("Event " + event.getClass().getSimpleName() + " has no handlers.");
            return event;
        }
        if (this.debug)
            CustomFacade.getLog().d("Event " + event.getClass().getSimpleName() + " has " + handlers.size() + " handlers.");
        for (EventHandler handler : handlers) {
            // Basic support for multi-stage events. More can be added later by specifying exactly which priority to be executed - executeEventPre(event, lessThanPriority) for example
            if (i == PRE && handler.getPriority() >= 0)
                continue;
            if (i == POST && handler.getPriority() < 0)
                continue;
            handler.execute(event);
        }
        return event;
    }
    public <T extends IEvent> T executeEvent(T event) {
        return this.executeEvent(event, ALL);
    }

    public void registerListener(final EventListener listener) {
        CustomFacade.getLog().v("Register event listener: " + listener);

        if (registeredListeners.contains(listener)) {
            CustomFacade.getLog().w("Listener already registred: " + listener);
            return;
        }

        Method[] methods = listener.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        this.registeredListeners.add(listener);
        for (final Method method : methods) {
            Event annotation = method.getAnnotation(Event.class);
            if (annotation == null)
                continue;

            Class<?>[] parameters = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (parameters.length != 1) // all listener methods should only have one parameter
                continue;

            Class<?> param = parameters[0];

            if (!method.getReturnType().equals(void.class)) {
                CustomFacade.getLog().w("Ignoring method due to non-void return: " + method.getName());
                continue;
            }

            if (IEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(param)) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Java just doesn't understand that this actually is a safe cast because of the above if-statement
                Class<? extends IEvent> realParam = (Class<? extends IEvent>) param;

                if (!this.bindings.containsKey(realParam)) {
                    this.bindings.put(realParam, new TreeSet<EventHandler>());
                }
                Collection<EventHandler> eventHandlersForEvent = this.bindings.get(realParam);
                CustomFacade.getLog().v("Add listener method: " + method.getName() + " for event " + realParam.getSimpleName());
                eventHandlersForEvent.add(createEventHandler(listener, method, annotation));
            }
        }
    }

    private EventHandler createEventHandler(final EventListener listener, final Method method, final Event annotation) {
        return new EventHandler(listener, method, annotation);
    }

    public void clearListeners() {
        this.bindings.clear();
        this.registeredListeners.clear();
    }

    public void removeListener(EventListener listener) {
        for (Entry<Class<? extends IEvent>, Collection<EventHandler>> ee : bindings.entrySet()) {
            Iterator<EventHandler> it = ee.getValue().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                EventHandler curr = it.next();
                if (curr.getListener() == listener) 
                    it.remove();
            }
        }
        this.registeredListeners.remove(listener);
    }
    public Map<Class<? extends IEvent>, Collection<EventHandler>> getBindings() {
        return new HashMap<Class<? extends IEvent>, Collection<EventHandler>>(bindings);
    }
    public Set<EventListener> getRegisteredListeners() {
        return new HashSet<EventListener>(registeredListeners);
    }
}
```

EventHandler.java

```
public class EventHandler implements Comparable<EventHandler> {
    private final EventListener listener;
    private final Method method;
    private final Event annotation;

    public EventHandler(EventListener listener, Method method, Event annotation) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.method = method;
        this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    public Event getAnnotation() {
        return annotation;
    }

    public Method getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
    public EventListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void execute(IEvent event) {
        try {
            method.invoke(listener, event);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
            CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
            CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        } 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(EventHandler " + this.listener + ": " + method.getName() + ")";
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return annotation.priority();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(EventHandler other) {
        // Because we are using a TreeSet to store EventHandlers in, compareTo should never return "equal".
        int annotation = this.annotation.priority() - other.annotation.priority();
        if (annotation == 0) 
            annotation = this.listener.hashCode() - other.listener.hashCode();
        return annotation == 0 ? this.hashCode() - other.hashCode() : annotation;
    }
}
```

EventListener.java

```
/**
 * Marker interface for classes that can be scanned for @Event annotations
 * @see Event
 */
public interface EventListener {}
```

IEvent.java

```
/**
 * Marker interface for events
 */
public interface IEvent {}
```

#### A simple JUnit test

Normally the class(es) that implements `EventListener` and the class that contains the `EventExecutor` are in entirely different packages.

```
public class EventTest implements EventListener {
    private EventExecutor events;
    private int messages;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.events = new EventExecutor();
        this.events.registerListener(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(0, messages);
        this.events.executeEvent(new SimpleEvent("Message"));
        assertEquals(1, messages);
    }

    @Event
    public void onSimpleEvent(SimpleEvent event) {
        messages++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being particularly pedantic, but I have the following observations:

## Annotation @Event

You go to great lengths to document `@Event` but not to document the `priority()` setting .... just saying... The priority is the sort of thing that needs documentation... is priority == 80 more or less important than priority == 0?

## EventExecutor

- There is nothing in here that suggests it is thread-safe. This may well be by design, but for a general-purpose system it will need to be, especially if you are advertising it as being a 'library' implementation.
- It is ['traditional' for `getListeners()` type methods to return an `array\[\]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getListeners%28java.lang.Class%29) rather than a List. I prefer the `array[]` because I like primitives, but, additionally, it is 'clearer' that you cannot add and remove items from the array.... Your code returns a list, but it is a modifyable List (even when empty). I believe I would prefer your code as (note how there's now only one lookup in the bindings map now as well):

...

```
    private static final EventHandler[] EMPTYHANDLERS = {};

    public EventHandler[] getListenersFor(Class<? extends IEvent> clazz) {
        Collection<EventHandler> handlers = this.bindings.get(clazz);
        if (handlers == null || handlers.isEmpty()) 
            return EMPTYHANDLERS; // No handlers so we return an empty list
        return handlers.toArray(new EventHandler[handlers.size()]);
    }
```

- In `registerListener()` I think you have inconsistent logging (why log when a single-argument method is non-void, bot not log when you have a multi-argument method?) I think the code should all be condensed to: `if (parameters.length == 1
           && IEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(parameters[0])
           && method.getReturnType().equals(void.class)) { ...`
- should `getBindings()` and `getRegisteredListeners()` really be public?

## EventHandler

I thin kit is naive to have the `execute(IEvent)` method have no error handling (it swallows all exceptions). I think you should at least document that there is an unchecked exception thrown from the method.... (these are significant problems) like:

```
/**
 * ......
 * throws IllegalStateException if it is not possible to invoke the event on a listener.
 */
public void execute(IEvent event) throws IllegalStateException {
    try {
        method.invoke(listener, event);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to call " + method, e1);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to call " + method, e1);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
        CustomFacade.getLog().e("Exception when performing EventHandler " + this.listener + " for event " + event.toString(), e1);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to call " + method, e1);
    } 
}
```

Also, what if the invoked method throws an exception... do you propagate that?

Why do you feel it is necessary to have `getMethod()`. The reflection you are doing should not be exposed....

Comment: If the invoked method throws an exception, that gets wrapped as an `InvocactionTargetException`, which is a checked exception and is therefore catched.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that some methods shouldn't be public, turned out that those methods weren't even used... :) Could you give some hints about what I need to do to ensure thread safety? Is it only about synchronizing `bindings` and `registeredListeners` (or use `Concurrent` versions of those types) or is there something else needed as well?

Comment: 1. avoid mutability when returning some state in collections by using `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` / `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` to make sure it will not be modified by anyone in a separate thread
2. use concurrent collections, like so:

`this.bindings = new ConcurrentHashMap();` and `this.registeredListeners = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();`